# How to replace get(), insert() and delete() functions of tk.Entry to canvas.create_text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

In Vkeyboard, the backspace (<-) key is used to remove the last typed text. I got the code form web that given example using `tk.Entry` widget as follow.

```
input = canvas.get(self.canvas_textbox, "1.0", 'end-2c')
self.canvas_textbox.delete("1.0", END)
self.canvas_textbox.insert("1.0", input, END)
```

where `self.canvas_textbox` is Entry that displays the text when the user press keys on Vkeyboard.

Now, I wanted to change the `tk.Entry` with `canvas.create_text`, So what I wrote the code for deleting the last typed character in the text is follow,

```
input = canvas.itemcget(self.canvas_textbox, "text")
canvas.delete(self.canvas_textbox,"1.0", END)
canvas.insert(self.canvas_textbox, input, "1.0",END)
```

But unfortunately, it's delete the whole text instead of just the last typed character.

Can anyone tell me why ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad English.

You're deleting it from 1 to END so it deletes the whole line. Try `len(entry.get()) - 1, END`. It's getting the numbers of how many characters are there inside the entry (from front to end) - 1, so its getting the last 2 number.

An example code:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def dellastword():
    entry.delete(len(entry.get()) - 1, END)
entry = Entry(root, width=20)
entry.pack()

button = Button(root, text='Delete Last Word', width=100, height=3, command=dellastword)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```